# Blade Template HTML Coloring Issue in Atom

Tags: php, html, laravel, atom-editor, laravel-blade

When I have Laravel code within the 'carrots' of the HTML element itself, all further HTML elements become discolored.

ex. `<body @php language_attributes() @endphp>` discolors `</body>`

If I use vanilla php, all is well and fine.

ALSO:

`<div class="somediv"> @php language_attributes() @endphp </div>`

Works fine

My hunch is that it has something to do with the "@" symbol within the HTML element. This isn't so much as an issue, as it is an annoyance!

Screenshot provided for reference.

[Code Screenshot - Note the red/orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k72S.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Blade templating support](https://atom.io/packages/language-blade)

Comment: I am using that very atom package, which is how the actual php syntax is being colored and indented correctly.